# Can I create gradle task in plugin with dependsOn parameter?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm creating a gradle plugin as below

```
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.extensions.create('testCoverageVerificationTask', TestCoverageVerificationPluginExtension)
        project.tasks.create('testCoverageVerification', TestCoverageVerificationTask)        
    }
}
```

And to use it, I need to add these to my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: my.package.MyPlugin

testCoverageVerificationTask {
    myreport = "testing report"
}

testCoverageVerification.dependsOn "myDependentTask"
```

However, I'm thinking it would be better to have the `dependsOn` as another parameter within the `testCoverageVerificationTask` so that it doesn't need to be defined separately. Is that feasible?

**note**: normal Task Definition could do this

```
task myTask(dependsOn: 'compile') {
    doLast {
        println 'I am not affected'
    }
}
```

But I can't do

```
testCoverageVerificationTask(dependsOn: "myDependentTask") {
    myreport = "testing report"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
Task task = project.tasks.create('testCoverageVerification', TestCoverageVerificationTask)
task.dependsOn("compile")
```

Comment: That's great. Can "compile" be a sent in parameter instead? As I might have slightly different dependent tasks across different module.

Comment: @Elye Sorry for delay. To be honest I don't know if it can be pass as a parameter.